# Как в ruby создаётся обмен данными между двумя пользователями?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Подскажите (можно ссылку даже дать или название книги и темы) как в ruby реализуется система запросов между двумя пользователями? Допустим игра в крестики нолики на рельсах между двумя - тремя пользователями одновременно.
Не могу задать запрос правильно в гугл. Надеюсь на хорошую подсказку.

Answer (score 1):

#### Ruby on Rails умеет только отвечать клиенту на запрос.

Соответственно, один клиент может оставить на сервере для другого сообщение, а другой обратиться за сообщениями для себя и получить его. Сообщения могут быть для конкретного адресата, а могут быть про конкретную игровую комнату. Модели заводите по усмотрению.

Если второй клиент ожидает сообщений в любой момент, он может периодически заходить за сообщениями для себя. Время доставки каждого сообщения таким образом будет ограничено периодом, с которым второй клиент запрашивает сообщения.

Но чем меньше будет этот период, тем больше клиент будет совершать запросов на единицу времени, и тем больше будет нагрузка на сервер. Не очень хорошо.

#### Хотя это не вся история.

В **Rails 5.0** добавили ActionCable. Для его работы нужен вебсервер, способный обрабатывать много висящих соединений одновременно (не Unicorn и уж тем более не Webrick!), и "вещалка", которая может быстро принимать сообщения и отпускать тех, кто их приносит, а сама передавать сообщения адресатам (по умолчанию в production в её роли используется Redis).

Процесс ActionCable и основной вебсервер могут быть разными процессами (а могут и не быть), но поскольку сообщения передаются через Redis, это неважно. Можно даже слать в этот же Redis сообщения другими службами того же проекта, и они тоже будут идти к пользователям, если будут в правильном формате.

Для клиента это выглядит, как будто приложение по определённому URL устанавливает соединение по протоколу [Websocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), откуда ему могут приходить сообщения **по инициативе сервера**. Код на JavaScript в браузере клиента может приходящие сообщения обрабатывать произвольным образом.

На сервере же появляется возможность швырять в "вещалку" сообщение, чтобы ActionCable разослал его всем, кто на такие сообщения подписан, **практически немедленно**, не дожидаясь явного запроса от пользователя (но при условии, что соединение уже установлено им ранее). Никакого "решения для устаревших браузеров без Websocket" (fallback) на данный момент не предусмотрено.

#### И это тоже не вся история.

На самом деле можно обмениваться данными без сервера. Ну, почти. И только иногда. Зависит от сетевого расположения обменивающихся клиентов, которые в этом случае уже скорее не клиенты, а **пи́ры** (peer-to-peer), равнозначные участники обмена данными.

В браузерах это реализовано технологией WebRTC. Она требует, чтобы клиенты каким-то образом обменялись адресами, по которым их можно попытаться найти (обычно для этого делается сигнальный сервер, а адреса получаются с помощью STUN-сервера), и попытались установить между собой **прямое** соединение. А если не получится (т. к. клиенты расположены ну очень плохо друг относительно друга), в дело вступает TURN-сервер, прокачивающий end-to-end-шифрованный трафик через себя.

На просторах интернета можно найти публичные STUN-серверы. Сигнальные тоже можно, но сложнее. А вот TURN уже вряд ли, это ж по сути прокси общего назначения. Можно обойтись и без TURN, но соединения достаточно часто будут отказываться устанавливаться. Можете проверить практически на любой маленькой WebRTC-поделке без TURN [вроде моего страшненького чатика](http://dside.ru/rtc-chat/#3028713481736618).

А ещё наметилась мода выключать WebRTC по той причине, что он приводит к "утеканию" реального IP-адреса, когда браузер работает "в особо анонимном режиме" через прокси или какой-нибудь VPN. В этом случае просто ничего работать не будет.

#### Но и это ещё не всё...

Мне приходилось встречать ActionCable-подобную конструкцию, ещё до релиза оного, где соединения обрабатывал процесс на Node.js с помощью socket.io, который реализует двухстороннюю связь несколько надёжнее и с уважением (умеренным) к старым браузерам.

Связь между ним и вебсервером можно поддерживать через тот же Redis или другой сервер обмена сообщениями, например RabbitMQ. Хотя имеет смысл, по-хорошему, только односторонняя, **от** вебсервера клиентам. Клиенты-то и обычные HTTP-запросы могут слать в любой момент.

---

### В общем, простых путей нет.